# Draw9Patch showing black lines

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am struggling to use the draw 9 patch.  I have created the following asset using the draw 9 patch

[image: draw9 patch]

However when I embed it into the app using the following code:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/open_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open_label"
        android:width="100dip"
       android:background="@drawable/simplebuttonbg"
        />
```

It doesn't work and shows the full image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I just fixed it in the process of documenting this question- so thought it might be useful to share: ( hope it helps someone)

1.Basically you can't just set button background to draw 9 patch.

1. You need to create a stateless drawable first with the data as such: in your drawables folder

   ```
   android:drawable="@drawable/simplebuttonbg_pressed"
   />
    <item
   android:state_focused="true" 
   android:state_enabled="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/simplebuttonbg_pressed" />
   ```
2. then you can apply it as a style or a background brilliantly!

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you mean to say "state list drawable", using the <selector> tag? Please provide the full xml. I am trying to use 9-patch drawable inside a <transition>, which in turn is set as a background for a LayoutView. Same problem: the 1px black border line is drawn.